# Better way to join in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Input 
Table A

```
catgId1 catg id2    catg id3    catg id4    catg id5
123     456          789            1011    1213
```

Table B

```
catgId
123
456
789
1011
1213
```

Output:Need to join two tables
I tried like

```
val results = df1.join(broadcast(df2),Array("catg Id").toSeq,"left_outer")
                 .join(broadcast(df2),Array("catg Id").toSeq,"left_outer")
```

Like this i tried 5 times renaming the column and i joined. Is there any better way apart from this. Please suggest.

Re queried output joining of two table i need few more columns i didn't mention here.

Comment: It is not clear what you need here. Please [edit] the question to provide more details. See [How to make good reproducible Apache Spark Dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/8371915)